# Can't upload files larger than 50kb with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm not sure why the my code below doesn't handle any files that larger than 50kb on my hosting though I works fine on localhost.

I tested many different file sizes and I'm pretty sure 50kb is its limit. If a file is larger than 50kb, it is never passed to process.php. If a file is smaller than 50kb, it would be passed to process.php ok.

Is there anyone can help me to fix this. I have been stuck in this problem for hours.

I did set `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini to 5M.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#img_uploader').on('change', function()
    {
       uploadFiles(this.files);
    }
});

function uploadFiles(fileList)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        var file = fileList[i];
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        formData.append('photos[]', file);
        formData.append('request', "uploadImg");
    }

    xhr.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(data);
            //convert_json_append_HTML(data);
        } else {
            alert('An error occurred!');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

**Updated: Test results**

I had spent 6 hours just to locate the problem.

This is really weired.

1/ 4 hours to review all Javascript and PHP code, logged every step to make sure nothing was wrong with the code.

- Tested on localhost with all scenarios. It worked perfectly.

2/ Changed these three varables didn't fix the problem regardless what limit I set. So I changed them to default.

- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- post_max_size

3/ Browser test:

Created 2 files: test_1.php and test_2.php. (basic HTML, no Javascript involved)

test_1.php

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

test_2.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
```

**HTTP**:

Chrome:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: passed

Firefox:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: passed

Internet Explorer:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: passed

**HTTPS**

Chrome:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: **failed**

Firefox:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: passed

Internet Explorer:

- Files < 50kb: passed
- Files > 50kb: passed

I'm not sure why the file larger than 50kb can not be passed from test_1.php to test_2.php on HTTPS protocol with Chrome. Is there anyone here know the reason? Or can try to test it on your own server.

Comment: checked the web server error log files?

Comment: Any errors that you get? You can check browser console, server's access logs.

Comment: There are 3 variables you need to check , upload_max_filesize, memory_limit, and post_max_size. For file upload all 3 come into the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

Kaspersky Internet Security automatically injects a script into any webpages loaded with Chrome (IE, and FF are not affected).

The script blocks any package larger than 50kb sent to web server on HTTPS protocol.

[image]

- Solutions:
  Kaspersky Internet Security > Settings > Additional > Network >

  - **Uncheck "Inject script into web traffic to interact with web pages"**

[image]

Comment: You saved me from killing myself! I was working for last 36 hours to solve this issue. Thanks a lot Man! Just one correction FF is also affected from this .. I don't know about EDGE

Answer (score 3):

You need to set desired values for 3 variables [Check this tutotial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/)

- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- post_max_size

Comment: These three variables are not reasons for my problem. The problem is still no matter how large the limit is. Please see my updated description.

Comment: Have you checked server log for HTTPS

Chrome:

Files > 50kb

Comment: I posted the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I same have like this problem and fixed by changing **post_max_size** in php.ini, In my case default is 8 MB increase to 20 MB, **It's work!**

Answer (score -1):

In my case turns out that `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit`, `post_max_size` in `php.ini` were set to the minimum below 20M, this can cause ajax not to send the request to the server's PHP file.

Comment: If you know the right solution, please write how to solve the problem by some simple instructions to do and test. Thanks